# How to recover windows encrypted files?

Tags: windows, file, encryption, properties

I have a partition for photos and at some point one of my little brothers encrypted almost half of the photos(via Right click on folder-> properties -> advanced -> encrypt).So now i have some 15 folders with photos that i can't open. I did not observe the change and i changed the OS. Now when i try to open a photo it says "Access denied!". The photos appear now with green title and in properties, they have the encrypted radio button checked and grayed. Is there any chance to recover these files?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below step to enable the encrypt radio button.
In my case I checked with window 8 OS.

```
1.  Press Windows Key + R combination, type put regedit in Run dialog box and hit Enter to open the Registry Editor.
2.  In the left pane of Registry Editor, navigate to:

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

3.  In the right pane of above shown window, look for the NtfsDisableEncryption named registry DWORD(REG_DWORD), since you’re facing the issue, you’ll find that this DWORD having its Value data set to 1. Double click on the same DWORD to modify:
4.  In the above shown window, change the Value data to 0. Click OK. You may now close the Registry Editor and reboot to get fixed.
```

For additional reference click this [Enableing encrypt option](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/encrypt-contents-to-secure-data-option-is-disabled)

Comment: Thanks! it enables the radio button but i can't decript the files. It gives "Permission denied! You need administrator privileges to do this action." even though i am on an admin user. Any other ideas?